# Managing website image assets

Tags: html, image, naming-conventions

I've got a bunch of images on my site, ranging from icons, to pictures, to html email images, to sprites, etc..

Rather than coming up with more and more complex image names and descriptive folder paths, does anyone have experience with any software that helps manage these images with categories and tagging?

It would have to be something simple and light that the engineers on my team could use to easily locate an image asset for a left pointing arrow, even if the name is something like larr.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from www root folder you should have something like this.

img (main images folder)

img/sprites (sprites in here)

img/icons (icons folder)

img/html-email (html email images)

Basically, try and keep file and folder names as descriptive as possible so everything is self documenting for example...

img_001.jpg ( you don't have any idea what this image could be of )
whereas bear-catching-fish.jpg gives you a clue as to what the image is all about

I'm not clear as to what you mean by tagging though.

EDIT
Just google 'image management software' and you should find what you need such as...
[Canto Cumulus](http://www.canto.com/en/promo/images.php?gclid=CKz3vMTvvKsCFSNItAodjF25vg)

Comment: Yeah, that's actually what I'm currently doing.  It would be nice, however, if there was some kind of software for managing images, such that I didn't have to rely on complicated naming conventions for finding my images.  So in other words, it would be nice to do a search for the keyword "flower" and get the filenames of all images that are tagged with the key word, "flower"

Comment: Tagging is not going to be any less time consuming than careful naming. Metadata, whether it's in the file name, folder structure or tags takes time